# Test Git repo size reduction after deleting a branch

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner, git-gc

Is there any way I can test how the deletion of several branches will affect the size of that git repo.
I have a git repo with 10 lived branches and hundreds of feature (short lived branches).

The repo is very large and slow to clone. GitLab shows 1.4 GB as the total size, [git-sizer](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) shows a blob total size of 8.4 GB.

I have tried tools such as [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove unwanted history, but I've only managed a reduction of 1.4 to 1 GB which is not really sufficient.

My strategy split my repo in 2 and also to use multiple forks to separate streams of work. I will also add push extension and size restriction in GitLab to stop pushing of junk. We've had problems with **.rar**, **.zip**, **.jar** files, personal backups mistakenly pushed etc.
However I also want to know if I can retain the history of my long lived branches.
So my questions:

1. Is it possible to see how much the size would be reduced if I deleted all the short lived branches?
2. Can this be achieved locally?
3. Or do I just have to duplicate everything to a test repo on GitLab and delete the branches on this test repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your three questions, I'd say that yes, it is possible to check this locally. (dependind on what you mean by *if I deleted all the short lived branches*, I'll assume they are not merged).

You can clone your repo, create local branches for the branches you want to keep, remove the remote, and gc aggresively.

However I don't think that'll help as much as using BGF repo cleaner to remove large binary files. If you need to track said binary files, you should switch to git-LFS for those files.

Your experience with BGF seems strange, I'd expect a much better reduction if you cleaned your repo properly.

Comment: The branches have been merged, they are mostly stale feature branches. I had to run BFG multiple times (sometimes with the same parameters, as it would find more to delete) deleting by filenames, blob IDs etc. I saw it increased the number of commits a lot, but only cleaned about 400 MB. It's possible I could be more aggressive with what I want to remove. But I really want to get to a new clean slate, as that may be the only way to get the required size reduction.  As these are remote branches I would then need to checkout all of them locally?

Comment: If they have been merged, you won't be able to remove them while also preserving history. What is the size of your current *code* in a clean state? (make a local copy of your repo, remove all non versioned files and then remove the .git directory)

Comment: The current code in a clean state as you requested is 121 MB.

Comment: The 121 MB  is for 1 of 10 of the long lived branches - there should be common code between them. Some of the short lived feature branches are merged, some are not. The reason I want to test how big the repo is without the short lived branches, is that I want to see if I can keep the long lived branches (with history) in a new forked repo structure (1 fork for each long lived branch), or I just need to transplant the current code (no history) for all of the long lived branches into each separate fork. - does that make sense?

Comment: yeah, unless in those 121MB there are many binary files that have changed often, the whole repo with cleaned history (BFG) shouldn't weight more than 300-400MB (ballpark estimate). So unless you can bring it down to that size with BFG, I would consider ditching that repo and starting from scratch again.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to post the steps I took when following A.M. answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57074193/1860867

Because the repo has nearly 600 branches and I wanted to test the effects of deleting nearly 350 of them.

1. I cloned the repository as normal.
2. I needed to created local branches for all 600 branches. I found a script to do that:

```
for i in `git branch -a | grep remote | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master`; do git branch --track ${i#remotes/origin/} $i; done
```

3. To verify the correct number of branches, I ran to following to count the number of local branches.

```
git branch | wc -l
```

4. Our branch names have a naming convention (luckily) and I wanted to test deleting all branches except those starting with prefix: **main_**. I was able to delete all other branches with the following script:

```
git branch | grep -v "main_" | xargs git branch -D
```

I ran the command in step 3 again to check if the number of branches and also just `git branch`, to see if the branch names were all correct.

5. To remove my remotes, first to get a listing of all remotes, I ran:

```
git remote -v
```

In this case the remote for fetch and push was **origin**, to remove it: I ran:

```
git remote rm origin
```

I then ran `git remote -v` again which returned nothing, to check the removal was successful.

6. To clean my local repository (and determine the size reduction after deletion of the local branches) I ran the command:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

After running the `git gc`, the repo size was reduced by ~ 600 MB, **git-sizer** showed similar reductions.